# Open a Viewcontroller on cell click - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to open a new view controller which has a textfield with the text of the cell clicked in a UITableView. Although I have already discovered how to get the clicked cell's information, I don't know how to push that value to the new ViewController. Here is my current code:

```
class NearbyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
    UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var nearbyTableView: UITableView!
    var myList: [String] = []


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellName
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellName

        print("row\(indexPath.row)")
        print("name: \(cellName)")

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: There is no reason at all to be creating a new cell in `didSelectRowAt`. And why is `cellName` in parentheses when being declared?

Comment: At least show your attempt to create and display the new view controller when the row is selected.

Comment: And in `cellForRowAt` you really should be creating the cell properly by dequeueing it from the table view. Please see one of countless tutorials on table views in iOS and Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some playground code that should help you.
Call `openDetails` func with parameters what you need from `didSelectRowAt`.

```
import UIKit

final class NearbyViewController: UIViewController {

    // Your controller implementation

    private func openDetails(cellName: String) {
        let detailsController = DetailedInfoViewController() // OR use storyboard.instantiate
        detailsController.cellName = cellName

        // You must have a Navigaion stack for your controller
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsController, animated: true)
    }
}

final class DetailedInfoViewController: UIViewController {
    var cellName: String!

    // Your controller implementation

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set data into view outlets
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this code it brings up the error:  Value of type 'NearbyViewController' has no member 'cell'

Comment: @MatthewBird This is just example how to declare var and setup it.
Declare property how it become in your controllers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to this so I am learning but I now have figured it out. Thank you for your example.

Comment: Sorry I just have one last question if thats alright. When I open my  new viewController, it says that the value of cellName is nil.

Comment: @MatthewBird maybe you can show me you full code in direct messages? I could help you understand and resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in your `didSelectIndexPath` method, you are accessing a cell and setting its label's text.

What you want to do is:

```
let viewController = ViewController()
viewController.textFieldText = cell.textLabel.text 
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Then once you have the `textFieldText` in your ViewController you can say:

```
textField.text = textFieldText
```

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  //  let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell") -> not correct
       let cell = tableView. cellForRowAt(indexpath)  // but don't need cell
    let (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = ViewController()
    viewController.textField.Text = cellName 
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```