# How to transfer data from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get a textfield in the second view controller to show the name of the cell clicked in a first view controller. When using a table view, should I push like below, or present as shown below. This is the current code I have

NearbyViewController

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]


     let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2") as! ShopViewController

    viewController.name = cellName

    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    let vct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2")
    self.present(vct!, animated: true, completion: nil)


    print("row\(indexPath.row)")
    print("name: \(cellName)")


}
```

ShopViewController

```
var name :String?

@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!



override func viewDidLoad() {

        print(name)



}
```

Comment: Why are you pushing the vc in navController as well as presenting the vc ?

Comment: This is essentially a repost of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681324/open-a-viewcontroller-on-cell-click-swift) which has several comments and even an accepted answer. Yet the code in this question doesn't seem to fix any of the issues you were told about in the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines :

```
let vct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2")
self.present(vct!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You are already pushing the same viewController in navigationController.
Your final code should be :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]

     let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2") as! ShopViewController
    viewController.name = cellName
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    print("row\(indexPath.row)")
    print("name: \(cellName)")
}
```

This should work only once you have set the viewController's identifier in storyboard. This is how you can do that :

[image]

Comment: I tried this to perform a segue programatically so thats what its for

Comment: My dear friend, you are already doing that before. Here : let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2") as! ShopViewController

Comment: I also tried changing this to perform segue, but it didn't work either

Comment: Have you set the vc's identifier in storyboard ?

Comment: when I removed the lines, it didn't go to the next page

Comment: Where have you defined and declared navigationController ?

Comment: How would I go about setting the vc's identifier

Comment: With my previous code it opened the new view controller, but just printed the value of name in the new view controller as nil.

Comment: Answer these : Are you able to navigate correctly ? And have you set the identifier in storyboard ?

Comment: Remove the needless creation of the cell. And remove the pointless parentheses when declaring cellName.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating 2 view controllers.
`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2")`
You change the value first then push, then you present it again. So the controller you are seeing is the second one, which you didn't set the value on.

Remove

`let vct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2")
self.present(vct!, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue with the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]

     let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2") as! ShopViewController
    viewController.name = cellName
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)


    print("row\(indexPath.row)")
    print("name: \(cellName)")


}
```

Comment: Remove the needless creation of the cell. And remove the pointless parentheses when declaring cellName.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Objective-c:

```
    UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    SecondViewController *nextView= [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];  // Please set "**SecondViewController**" to the secondController's storyboardID from storyboard. 

    nextView.strUserName = @"username" ;   // or you can transfer any type of data array or dictionary.

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

The function `viewDidLoad` is getting called before the `name` variable is getting set.

Try moving the `print()` to `viewWillAppear` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but  unfortunately, this didn't work

Comment: I think your code has at least a couple issue. This may be part of it. Good luck.